# Other criteria to tableview's section?

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qtquick2

I'm asking me if it's possible to use other "criteria" than "FirstCharacter" and "FullString" with the "section.criteria" to tableview's section.

For example, I need to pick the two firsts characters of the "section.property", to extract some data and sort it.

I've the property "12:30" and i want to extract "12" to display it in row section, and not just pick the first character "1".

I don't find, but i hope there a solution somewhere.

[docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#section.property-prop):

> section.criteria holds the criteria for forming each section based on section.property. This value can be one of:
>
> **ViewSection.FullString (default)** - sections are created based on the section.property value.
>
> **ViewSection.FirstCharacter** - sections are created based on the first character of the section.property value (for example, 'A', 'B', 'C' sections, etc. for an address book)
>
> A case insensitive comparison is used when determining section boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can add a new role to your model (for instance, 'sectionRole') and use it for groupping items in the view?

Comment: Yes, 

It's what i've made !

I've created new role in my tableview, and i don't display him as a column (like my other roles actually). 
I use it to extract twice first character of my hour section, and as "section.property"...

It's seems worked good !

Thank you Arman !